# Generalised Möbius inversion formula.

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-inversion

Lets recall the Möbius inversion formula:

If we have two arithmetic functions $f,F$, such:

$$F(n)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)$$ then we have:

$$f(n)=\sum_{d|n}F(d)\mu(\frac{n}{d})$$

Suppose now that we have another arithmetic functions $g , G$:

$$G(n,a,b)=\sum_{d|an+b}g(d)$$

> Express g(n) in terms of $G(d,a,b)$, where $a,b$ are fixed.

I was trying to apply the proof of the Möbius inversion formula to solve this problem, but with no result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Did you mean $g(d)$. What about $G(n,1,0)$

Comment: Ok. I am editing my question in a moment.

Comment: $G(n,2,1)$ doesn't depend on $g(2)$

Comment: If $g$ is supported on $a\Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}+b$  then you can recover it uniquely from $G(.,a,b)$. Otherwise you can't and you need to investigate $\ker : g\to G(.,a,b)$.

Comment: If given $G(.,a,b)$ what you want is any function $h$ such that $G(n,a,b)=\sum_{d| an+b} h(d)$ then simply set $h(n)=\sum_{ad+b|n}\mu(n/(ad+b))G(d,a,b)$.